SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in React
 function SubmitButton(){ return ( <button>Submit</button> ); }
Newbie here, trying to make a dropdown for user to select a year and hit Submit. I don't understand why I keep getting a syntax error after the return statement.
here's the rest of my code so far.
import React, { onChange } from 'react';

function SubmitButton(){
  return (
    <button>Submit</button>
  );
}

const dropdownYear = () => {
  const arr = [];

  const start = new Date().getFullYear() - 100;
  const current = new Date().getFullYear();

  for (let i = current; i >= start; i--){
    arr.push(<option value={i}>{i}</option>)
  }
}

function BirthdayField(){
  <select 
    className='bd-form'
    name='year'
    onChange={onChange}
    value={year}
  >
    <option value='0'>Year</option>
    {dropdownYear()}
  </select>
}


export default function MyApp(){
  return (
    <div>
      <BirthdayField />
      <SubmitButton />
    </div>
  );
}


Sounds like the file is being parsed as JavaScript and not jsx.  Is the file extension jsx?

BirthdayField misses the return statement

BirthdayField is missing the return statement.

Also dropdownYear returns nothing.

return type is missing in BirthdayField,
There are other issues with the snippet you provided,value is not defined anywhere and you need to pass a callback function instead of onChange from react


function BirthdayField() { 
  return (
    <select className='bd-form' name='year' onChange={()=>{}} value={year}>
      <option value='0'>Year</option>
      {dropdownYear()}
    </select>
  );
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



